# Module cannot make absolute imports to its own branch in the package tree?

Tags: python, import, coding-style

If you have a package structure as this:

```bsh
foldertest/
  __init__.py
  a/
    __init__.py
    asub/
      __init__.py
  b/
    __init__.py
```

`foldertest.__ini__.py`:

```py
import a
```

`foldertest.a.__init__.py`:

```py
import foldertest.a.asub
print foldertest.a.asub
```

If I from the folder above `foldertest/` run the python shell and issue `import foldertest` I receive the following error:

```
>>> import foldertest
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "foldertest/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    import foldertest.a
  File "foldertest/a/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    print foldertest.a.asub
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'a'
```

Whereas if I would change `foldertest.a.__init__.py` to import `foldertest.b` instead and try printing that I would receive:

```
>>> import foldertest
<module 'foldertest.b' from 'foldertest/b/__init__.pyc'>
>>>
```

Am I doing something wrong or is not possible to use absolute referencing to a package's/module's own branch in the package tree? (also PyDev seems to disapprove of writing imports like this) I wanted to have absolute package references for consistency. Also I do not know of any "best practice" for writing import statements or structuring packages that suggest against this.

Comment: Best practice is to use relative imports within a package -- that's what they're for.

Comment: Doesn't the style guide recommend you not to use relative imports?  Quoting it, it says: _"Relative imports for intra-package imports are highly discouraged. Always use the absolute package path for all imports."_ http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports 
Am I missing something?

Comment: I never understood PEP-8 on that one. If you use the dotted syntax from PEP 328 (`from . import a`) then there's no problem.

Comment: But shouldn't absolute import paths still work?